# Please explain overflow:hidden 's effect on backgrounds?

Tags: css

I know when your elements background is not behind all of its content, (eg: because of floated elements, positioned elements, margin) adding `overflow:hidden` fixes the issue, forcing the background to show behind those elements.

For example see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495952/background-and-css-floats) and meder's answer.

However, when doing this, it is not hiding any overflowing content, so how does setting this effect anything at all?

Basically I know it works, but I want to understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a new block formatting context, which clears the floats.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

And.. it *does* clip overflowing content: http://jsfiddle.net/rDmhn/

Comment: I think the OP's point regarding clipping was that he was only aware of `overflow: hidden`'s clipping effects, and was curious as to why it would any effect at all if there were nothing to clip.

Comment: @Matchu you are absolutely right. The first part of the answer still kinda answers my question though, I mean he did answer my question but I still have a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: @John: oh, yeah, it's still the right answer :) I was just clarifying why the second bit wasn't really necessary. Don't forget to click the check mark if you think this satisfactorily answers your question :D